# How do I test a CiviCRM upgrade script?

Tags: sql, developer, upgrade

I have a PR that adds a file CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/4.7.alpha1.mysql.tpl.  How should I go about testing this code?

Comment: Note that the more common case is to be inserting upgarde code into a file like this. In both cases the important thing is to test the upgrade code works properly. JMA has found that it is useful to test db upgrade code against a variety of dbs that have been found in the wild, as well as the tests that automatically check upgrades on the default db.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have installed [civicrm-buildkit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit) and configured [civibuild](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/doc/civibuild.md), then you can use the tutorial steps at [Daily Coding: Upgrade Tests](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/doc/daily-coding.md#upgrade-tests).

If you don't use civibuild, then you can piece-together a similar workflow using [civicrm-upgrade-test](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-upgrade-test/).

For more discussion about writing upgrade logic, see [Upgrade Reference](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrade+Reference) on the wiki.

For a general, high-level overview of automated tests (including upgrade tests), see [Testing](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Testing) on the wiki.